# Only NUll value getting from middleware Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

When I tried to get value from middleware to construct of controller it is getting Null

My Controller Code

```
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $moduleCode = "property_module";
            $middleware = app()->make(PermissionAndRoleCheck::class, ['moduleCode' => $moduleCode]);
            $this->userModulePermissions = $request->attributes->get('userModulePermissions');
            dd($this->userModulePermissions);
            return $next($request);
        });
```

My Middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $moduleCode = "property_module";
        $role = Auth::user()->user_type;
        $propertyModuleId ="6ca38e62-6c50-438d-bdcd-0db8f563ac4c";
        $roleId = "b9e57901-8077-4962-aad9-3329d8e02323";
        $module = Module::where('module_code', $moduleCode)->first();
        $userModulePermissions = Permission::where('role_id', $roleId)
            ->where('module_id', $propertyModuleId)
            ->first();

        if (!$userModulePermissions) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'No Data here.'], 403);
        }

        app()->instance('userModulePermissions', $userModulePermissions);

        return $next($request);
    }
```

When I directly put query in controller I am getting values

| id | role_id | module_id | permissions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40469677-0331-4717-814b-7102f4b37d35 | beb60b0e-bed4-4a77-9901-47113bbcba67 | 6ca38e62-6c50-438d-bdcd-0db8f563ac4c | add,edit,view |

When Write query in controller I am getting results, When I tried the same in Middleware not getting values